# Excel内部の関数やグラフの指定方法などはオフトピックですか？

Tags: 討議

こちらの質問を確認した時に閉じるに4票が入っていたのですが、Excelの操作におけるプログラミング的な質問はオフトピックになるのでしょうか？

[エクセルグラフの軸色の一部変更](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/25069/%E3%82%A8%E3%82%AF%E3%82%BB%E3%83%AB%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A9%E3%83%95%E3%81%AE%E8%BB%B8%E8%89%B2%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%80%E9%83%A8%E5%A4%89%E6%9B%B4)

何を「プログラミング的」とするかの判断は難しいと思いますが、英語版や superuser.com を見る限り受け入れられてるように思います。

この辺りの基準は日本語版ではどうなっているのでしょうか？

Comment: [参考](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/292)。個人的にはこれはありです。この質問を受け入れなかったら、将来にSuper User日本語版を立ち上がるユーザーが少なくなります。現在Super User日本語版がないので、Stack Overflow日本語版でいいんじゃないですかと個人的に思います。最終的な判断はコミュニティになりますので、皆様の意見を集まりましょう（現在質問自体は４つのクローズ票で改善待ち寸前になっています）。

Comment: なるほど。ちなみにこういう「私はオフトピックではないと考える。」という意志の表明はプラス票を投じる意外に何かありますか？ 質問へのコメントは荒れるかと思って控えておいたのですが。

Comment: ご自身の[レビューキュー](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/review/close)に当該投稿があれば「オープンのままにする」という票を、クローズ後であれば質問ページから再オープン票を投じることができます。個人的にはメタ投稿へのリンクを添えたコメントぐらいはしてもいいのではと考えていますが、何か改善できそうな点があればそれをコメントするのもよいかと。本来の用途に沿っていますし、関心を持っているというアピールにもなります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。コメントをつけておきました。

Answer (score 1):

個人的に、オフトピックであるかどうかの判断は、「コードを書くことに関連するか」で判断してます。

以下、それを踏まえた上での今回のケースの考察です。

問題を一見した際には、これはただ単に Excel のグラフの設定の仕方の問題かと思い、オフトピック票を投票しました。

解答を見ると、たしかにコード的な解決であって、その意味ではオントピックなような気がしてきます。

オントピックかどうかの判定は問題にひもづくものであって、回答とは無関係に決定されるべきであるとするならば、Excel が難しいのは、コード的な解決が適しているのかそうでないのかが、一見してわかりにくいところなのかなと思っています。

もう一回レビューが回ってくれば、自分は多分オープンの方に投票しますが、それは回答によってコード的な問題に帰着できることが示されたからであって、今回の問題だけが提示された段階でこれをクローズ票にしないような投票基準が設けられるか、と考えると若干疑問に思ってます。

Comment: 英語版では質問が微妙ですが、回答がいいから質問を受け入れるケースが多いです。回答を無視してはいけないと思います。良い回答があるイコール質問はメリット無しとは言えませんが、回答と質問の質が合わない場合、質問を編集して改善したらどうですか？

Comment: @jmac 質問者の(本当に)ほしかったものから乖離する可能性があるので、質問の意図をオントピックになるように修正してしまうのはどうなんだろう、と思ったりもします。

Comment: もちろん最初に確認してから回答した方がいいが、確認しなくても、回答したかったら回答してもいいと思います。前向きに動き出したら後で訂正ができるので、悩む必要はないと思います。（今回の場合に悩んだのは「棒の色又は軸のテキストの色のどっちかな？」と悩みました）

Answer (score 0):

私もクローズ票を投じているのですが、
オフトピックではなく曖昧な質問だと投票しました。
関数や、VBAで実現するのか、GUIの機能だけで実現したいのかが不明だったためです。
GUIの機能だけで実装するのであれば私はオフトピックかと思います。